# My OpenGL program stops running when I use the Assimp importer.ReadFile

Tags: opengl, assimp

I'd like to ask a question about assimp. When I try to run my code the compiler and the linker give me no errors but it crashes when I use the ReadLine function, but if I comment the part in which I use it the program works fine.
Here's the model.cpp file:

```
#include "Model.h"

Model::Model(GLchar *path)
{
    this->LoadModel(path);
}


Model::~Model() { 
}


void Model::Draw(Shader shader)
{
    for (GLuint i = 0; i < this->meshes.size(); i++)
    {
        this->meshes[i].Draw(shader);
    }
}


void Model::LoadModel(string path)
{

    // Read file via ASSIMP
    Assimp::Importer importer;

    const aiScene *scene = importer.ReadFile(path, aiProcess_Triangulate | aiProcess_FlipUVs);

    // Check for errors
    if (!scene || scene->mFlags == AI_SCENE_FLAGS_INCOMPLETE || !scene->mRootNode) // if is Not Zero
    {
        cout << "ERROR::ASSIMP:: " << importer.GetErrorString() << endl;
        return;
    }
    // Retrieve the directory path of the filepath

    this->directory = path.substr(0, path.find_last_of('/'));

    // Process ASSIMP's root node recursively
    this->processNode(scene->mRootNode, scene);

}

// Processes a node in a recursive fashion. Processes each individual mesh located at the node and repeats this process on its children nodes (if any).
void Model::processNode(aiNode* node, const aiScene* scene)
{
    // Process each mesh located at the current node
    for (GLuint i = 0; i < node->mNumMeshes; i++)
    {
        // The node object only contains indices to index the actual objects in the scene.
        // The scene contains all the data, node is just to keep stuff organized (like relations between nodes).
        aiMesh* mesh = scene->mMeshes[node->mMeshes[i]];

        this->meshes.push_back(this->processMesh(mesh, scene));
    }

    // After we've processed all of the meshes (if any) we then recursively process each of the children nodes
    for (GLuint i = 0; i < node->mNumChildren; i++)
    {
        this->processNode(node->mChildren[i], scene);
    }
}

Mesh Model::processMesh(aiMesh *mesh, const aiScene *scene)
{
    // Data to fill
    vector<Vertex> vertices;
    vector<GLuint> indices;
    vector<Texture> textures;

    // Walk through each of the mesh's vertices
    for (GLuint i = 0; i < mesh->mNumVertices; i++)
    {
        Vertex vertex;
        glm::vec3 vector; // We declare a placeholder vector since assimp uses its own vector class that doesn't directly convert to glm's vec3 class so we transfer the data to this placeholder glm::vec3 first.

                          // Positions
        vector.x = mesh->mVertices[i].x;
        vector.y = mesh->mVertices[i].y;
        vector.z = mesh->mVertices[i].z;
        vertex.Position = vector;

        // Normals
        vector.x = mesh->mNormals[i].x;
        vector.y = mesh->mNormals[i].y;
        vector.z = mesh->mNormals[i].z;
        vertex.Normal = vector;

        // Texture Coordinates
        if (mesh->mTextureCoords[0]) // Does the mesh contain texture coordinates?
        {
            glm::vec2 vec;
            // A vertex can contain up to 8 different texture coordinates. We thus make the assumption that we won't
            // use models where a vertex can have multiple texture coordinates so we always take the first set (0).
            vec.x = mesh->mTextureCoords[0][i].x;
            vec.y = mesh->mTextureCoords[0][i].y;
            vertex.TexCoords = vec;
        }
        else
        {
            vertex.TexCoords = glm::vec2(0.0f, 0.0f);
        }

        vertices.push_back(vertex);
    }

    // Now wak through each of the mesh's faces (a face is a mesh its triangle) and retrieve the corresponding vertex indices.
    for (GLuint i = 0; i < mesh->mNumFaces; i++)
    {
        aiFace face = mesh->mFaces[i];
        // Retrieve all indices of the face and store them in the indices vector
        for (GLuint j = 0; j < face.mNumIndices; j++)
        {
            indices.push_back(face.mIndices[j]);
        }
    }

    // Process materials
    if (mesh->mMaterialIndex >= 0)
    {
        aiMaterial* material = scene->mMaterials[mesh->mMaterialIndex];
        // We assume a convention for sampler names in the shaders. Each diffuse texture should be named
        // as 'texture_diffuseN' where N is a sequential number ranging from 1 to MAX_SAMPLER_NUMBER.
        // Same applies to other texture as the following list summarizes:
        // Diffuse: texture_diffuseN
        // Specular: texture_specularN
        // Normal: texture_normalN

        // 1. Diffuse maps
        vector<Texture> diffuseMaps = this->LoadMaterialTexture(material, aiTextureType_DIFFUSE, "texture_diffuse");
        textures.insert(textures.end(), diffuseMaps.begin(), diffuseMaps.end());

        // 2. Specular maps
        vector<Texture> specularMaps = this->LoadMaterialTexture(material, aiTextureType_SPECULAR, "texture_specular");
        textures.insert(textures.end(), specularMaps.begin(), specularMaps.end());
    }

    // Return a mesh object created from the extracted mesh data
    return Mesh(vertices, indices, textures);
}

// Checks all material textures of a given type and loads the textures if they're not loaded yet.
// The required info is returned as a Texture struct.
vector<Texture> Model::LoadMaterialTexture(aiMaterial *mat, aiTextureType type, string typeName)
{
    vector<Texture> textures;

    for (GLuint i = 0; i < mat->GetTextureCount(type); i++)
    {
        aiString str;
        mat->GetTexture(type, i, &str);

        // Check if texture was loaded before and if so, continue to next iteration: skip loading a new texture
        GLboolean skip = false;

        for (GLuint j = 0; j < textures_loaded.size(); j++)
        {
            if (textures_loaded[j].path == str)
            {
                textures.push_back(textures_loaded[j]);
                skip = true; // A texture with the same filepath has already been loaded, continue to next one. (optimization)

                break;
            }
        }

        if (!skip)
        {   // If texture hasn't been loaded already, load it
            Texture texture;
            texture.id = TextureFromFile(str.C_Str(), this->directory);
            texture.type = typeName;
            texture.path = str;
            textures.push_back(texture);

            this->textures_loaded.push_back(texture);  // Store it as texture loaded for entire model, to ensure we won't unnecesery load duplicate textures.
        }
    }

    return textures;
}

GLint TextureFromFile(const char *path, string directory)
{
//Generate texture ID and load texture data
string filename = string(path);
filename = directory + '/' + filename;
GLuint textureID;
glGenTextures(1, &textureID);

int width, height;

unsigned char *image = SOIL_load_image(filename.c_str(), &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);

// Assign texture to ID
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

// Parameters
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
SOIL_free_image_data(image);

return textureID;
}
```

The part of Model.cpp that causes the problem is this one:

```
 const aiScene *scene = importer.ReadFile(path, aiProcess_Triangulate |                  aiProcess_FlipUVs);

// Check for errors
if (!scene || scene->mFlags == AI_SCENE_FLAGS_INCOMPLETE || !scene->mRootNode) // if is Not Zero
{
    cout << "ERROR::ASSIMP:: " << importer.GetErrorString() << endl;
    return;
}
// Retrieve the directory path of the filepath

this->directory = path.substr(0, path.find_last_of('/'));

// Process ASSIMP's root node recursively
this->processNode(scene->mRootNode, scene);
```

The part of the main in which I create my model object:

```
Model ourModel("Object/models/nanosuit.obj");
```

I've been searching for a solution for an entire day. If someone could help me figure it out I would be really glad. If you need other parts of the code please tell me.

Comment: What error does it tell you as it crashes?

Comment: I wrote crash but I don't know if it is the right term. OpenGL gives a blank window and after some seconds it says "The program "Name program" stopped working"

Comment: You explicitly said "it crashes when I use the ReadLine function" ?

Comment: Yes I said that but it doesn't tell me the actual problem is in the ReadLine function. I know the error is in that part of the code only because because if I comment it the program works fine. If I don't comment that part the program stops working before Assimp can give any error message through GetErrorString() method

Comment: I meant ReadFile function

Answer (score 0):

At first please check if this is an error in our model-file. You can use the Assimp-Viewer for importing the model. If you can see it there this is a sign that your code is broken.

If the model-loader shows you an error the importer or the model could be corrupt. If this is the case: just reopen the issue on the Asset-Importer-Lib project page ( see https://github.com/assimp/assimp/issues/1215 ).

Comment: I can see it with AssimpViewer and I use the same code of a tutorial I was following on youtube that works

Comment: Hm, sounds bad. Could you please provide the model?

Comment: https://github.com/SonarSystems/Modern-OpenGL-Tutorials/tree/master/%5BMODEL%20LOADING%5D/%5B16%5D%20Model%20Class/res/models