# how to build assimp as a static lib (/MT)?

Tags: cmake, shared-libraries, static-libraries, linker-errors, assimp

I've been trying to build assimp as a static library using CMakeGUI.
I got assimp-3.1.1 for the source code. build location at assimp-3.1.1/build.
I got 2 options which appear to be relevant: ASSIMP_BUILD_STATIC_LIB and BUILD_SHARED_LIBS.
In my attempt to build a static lib I enabled the first and disabled the second. I clicked configure again and generated the solution. In the solution I clicked 'Build Solution'. Then in assimp-3.1.1/build/code/Debug I found the assimpd.lib file which *should* be in /MT. But it's not. When I link it in my project I get linker errors like

> Error  LNK2038 mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value >'MTd_StaticDebug' in main.obj Mush3D  C:\VSProjects\Mush3D\Mush3D\assimpd.lib(Importer.obj)   1

in the assimpd.lib file. So the lib is in MDd (my project is in MTd).
In the command prompt for VS22 I entered "dumpbin /directives "C:\assimp-3.1.1\build\code\Debug\assimpd.lib" " to see its version and found the following:

> Linker Directives
>
> ---
>
> /FAILIFMISMATCH:_CRT_STDIO_ISO_WIDE_SPECIFIERS=0
> /FAILIFMISMATCH:_MSC_VER=1900
> /FAILIFMISMATCH:_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=2
> /FAILIFMISMATCH:RuntimeLibrary=MDd_DynamicDebug
> /DEFAULTLIB:msvcprtd
> /FAILIFMISMATCH:annotate_vector=0
> /FAILIFMISMATCH:annotate_string=0
> /DEFAULTLIB:MSVCRTD
> /DEFAULTLIB:OLDNAMES

note that the DEFAULTLIBs msvcprtd and MSVCRTD are also /MDd.

I think the /FAILIFMISMATCH might be responsible. I can't find it in the assimp solution, the CMakeList in assimp-3.1.1, or the CMakeCache in assimp-3.1.1/build

I don't know where else to look for /FAILIFMISMATCH to change them (if changing them is the solution).
If the /FAILIFMISMATCH lines aren't responsible for my lib being built as MDd, what else could it be? Is there another setting I missed? I can't change it for the entire solution through the solution properties page.

Should I just give up building assimp as a static lib? Due to some mismatches between 3 libs I used I decided to build some of them again and chose /MT (my bullet physics libs were already in /MT), but maybe switching the other 2 to /MD will be easier than getting assimp in /MT...

Edit: It appears building the Bullet physics libs in /MD is not something Bullet support, and thus for me practically impossible... so if Bullet likes being static and assimp likes being dynamic, what should I do?

Comment: It's a little bit confusing. You build assimp as a static lib, it doesn't mean that you will link to static vc runtime. If you want to control vc runtime, there is https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY.html. And your assertion about Bullet is incorrect, MD is obviously supported (Buller CMakeLists does some babysitting through a `USE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY_DLL` custom option: https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3/blob/3.25/CMakeLists.txt#L64-L67).

Comment: @SpacePotatoes the distinction you make between the assimp libs Runtime and the vc runtime is something I think I heard before. While learning about these things I read about an issue where a lib had one runtime lib (let's say /MT) and it itself linked to a MSVC lib with a different runtime lib (let's say /MD). Is this the same distinction, or another layer? I'm finding these layers confusing, and most of my search prompts just lead to ''static vs dynamic'' questions. CRT documentation is too general. Do you know how I could find good explanations? what prompt could I search?

Comment: A library can be either shared or static, and being linked either to static or dynamic CRT. It's strongly recommended to build all your libs against the same CRT. Assuming that your libs are built with CMake, you have CMake >= 3.15 and you want /MD, you can pass `-DMSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY=MultiThreadedDLL -DCMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0091=NEW` during CMake configuration of these libs, it should ensure some consistency. A package manager like conan or vcpkg may help also, they take care of these details and patch broken build files which are doing crazy things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build assimp as a static library you need to switch to the latest version 5.2.5 or the latest master. Get the source, go to the root of the repo / source and use cmake to generate the project files:

```
cmake CMakeLists.txt -dBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF
```

Now you shall be able to build the static library.

Comment: I didn't notice I was using an outdated version of assimp. I did manage to build assimp as a static lib, linked to static CRT in the older version by adding MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY to the CMakeList, but the latest version 5.2.5 does have an option USE_STATIC_CRT, which does the same I assume. In any case both seemed to work. Unfortunately I've ran into another issue [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43000716/my-opengl-program-stops-running-when-i-use-the-assimp-importer-readfile) which might be related and I can't seem to solve, but I'll make another post about that one.